# Round cube login connection to storage server failed

Tags: 12.04, mail-server, roundcube

I have multiple domains working on my mail server, and all are working normally,

I configured new mail domain "newdomain.ae" normally on mysql mail db, created new user, inbox was created on server,

But when i tried to login to my account on the new mail on round cube, i got the error "login connection to storage server failed"

Round cube's logs were:

```
[01-Feb-2016 23:00:01 +0200]: IMAP Error: Login failed for myaccount@newdomain.ae from 2.2.2.2. Could not connect to newdomain.ae:143: Connection refused in /var/www/webmail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 184 (POST /mail/?_task=login&_action=login)
```

**Note:** the application server is hosted on another different server under domain "newdomain.ae"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could finally fixed it, Roundcube default configuration was resolving the @newdomain.ae to the app server not the mail server,

I modified the host parameter for both smtp and imap in the roundcube configuration file "config/main.inc.php" $rcmail_config['smtp_server'] and $rcmail_config['default_host'] to the mail server IP, and it finally worked :)